# Generic C# Function That Return Value From Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

The following function get parameters and return first value from sql server table. Its generic and very easy to use to get one value but it has security vulnerability of SQL Injection.  May anyone help to alter the code to make it a parametric or any other way to secure for SQL Injection?

```
public static string getFieldValue(string tableName, string returnField, string whereCondition)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString());
            SqlDataReader reader;
            string returnValue;
        try
        {
            string sql;
            if (whereCondition != "")
                sql = "SELECT " + returnField + " as ReturnField FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + whereCondition;
            else
                sql = "SELECT " + returnField + " as ReturnField FROM " + tableName;


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                returnValue = reader["ReturnField"].ToString();
                reader.Close();
                return returnValue;
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Close();
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: This should actually be okay, because it only uses cmd.ExecuteReader().  No call can possibly insert, update or delete, right?

Comment: Well you can't parameterize table or column names. You could wrap both the column and table names with QUOTENAME which help considerably. The issue is that you are trying to create a generic method to query any column from any table. This is like creating the "one method to rule them all".

Comment: @Mr.B this is ABSOLUTELY NOT OK!!! It is wide open to sql injection. Just because the method name is ExecuteReader does not make this safe. On the sql side it just executes the string passed in which can contain multiple statements.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteReader();  can delete delete records after the ; of first statement. I have test the injection.

Comment: @Sean Lange  Absolutely right

Comment: You can't really fix problems with `whereCondition` because it needs to be evaluated as part of the SQL statement. Are you sure it's a good idea to have this method in the first place? Maybe you should just implement the database fetches separately where it's needed.

Comment: if the possible `returnField` and `tableName` combinations are small, why don't you write stored procedures and pass the name of the stored procedure to your data access method? stored procedures can have default parameter values. So you may or not pass the parameter based on your `whereCondition`.